# Connecting to instrument via GPIB using PyVISA in Python

Tags: python, gpib, pyvisa

I am working on the acquisition of electrical contact resistance, for which I will be using a Keithley 2400 sourcemeter and a Keithley 2182a nanovoltmeter. Both of the instruments are connected to a Windows computer via USB with a Keithley KUSB-488b adapter.

I am working with Python, the Pyvisa module, and the National Instruments backend (NI VISA) to create a script that will allow me to conduct the measurements needed. However I am running into trouble communicating with the instruments. I have run a couple of simple scripts, based on the official documentation provided by the developers of Pyvisa, but am unable to connect with either instrument. The following simple block of code may aid my explanation:

```
>>> import pyvisa
>>> rm = pyvisa.ResourceManager()
>>> rm.list_resources()
('ASRL3::INSTR', 'ASRL4::INSTR', 'ASRL8::INSTR', 'ASRL14::INSTR')
>>> inst = rm.open_resource(' # Instrument address here # ')
>>> print(inst.query("*IDN?")
```

The result in line 4 should give me a list of the addresses of my instruments. However, none of these are correct, hence I get a timeout error (`VI_ERROR_TMO`) when I try the four addresses provided by line 4. The expected output in line 4 of this simple code block would be the GPIB addresses of both instruments, as per the documentation. I tried using the KI-488 Diagnostics Tool to communicate with both devices. Both of which I successfully communicated with. The SMU's address is GPIB::24 and the nanovoltmeter is GPIB::7.

I also tried passing the GPIB addresses that I obtained from the diagnostic tools in more complex scripts (current sweep). However this resulted in

> pyvisa.errors.VisaIOError: VI_ERROR_LIBRARY_NFOUND (-1073807202)

I searched online for similar errors, most of which are an outcome of missing dll or incorrect bitness. However this is not my case, since a simple `python -m visa info` proves that the backends implemented are correct. I also tried passing the `resourcemanager( path )`, however that was also unsuccessful.

Additionally I tried installing Keithley I/O Layer, but I was unsuccessful nonetheless. Also, in the Keithley communicator both devices do in fact appear with their corresponding GPIB address. The issue is working with Python and the proper address.

Comment: I've not used the KUSB-488b before, however, from your description this seems like an issue with the KUSB-488b driver, or VISA may not be the correct version or has an installation issue. Are you able to use the NIMAX tool to see the instrument and communicate? even if you can see them in with the KI-488 Diagnostics Tool, if NImax is not able to see them then pyvisa will not be able to see them.

Comment: Hi Zircatron, thanks for your replay!
I too believe that it is an issue with the NI-VISA, but not sure what causes it. I updated the KUSB driver and NI-VISA. I am able to detect both instruments with the NIMAX tool, with their corresponding GPIB addresses. There lies my confusion, NIMAX picks them up correctly, but I cannot see them with the visa dll. I installed pyvisa-py and passes '@py' when calling the ResourceManager() and now I can see and communicate with both instruments within python. However I still can't explain why NI-VISA is not working.

Comment: Try uninstalling NI-VISA and install Keysight Connection expert.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve a similar problem with the same KUSB-488B adapter by using the  the "Keysight IO Libraries Suite" from [Keysight's website](https://www.keysight.com/main/software.jspx?ckey=2175637) instead of NI-VISA.

On my PC running Windows 10 (19.09, 64-bit) I did the following:

- Uninstall the KUSB-488B driver from the Device Manager.
- Uninstall NI-VISA, reboot.
- Remove all remaining items mentioning "VISA", "NI", "GPIB" or "488" in the list of installed programs in Windows' settings app. Reboot.
- Install the latest KUSB-488B driver. During installation, choose the "Keithley command compatible" option (there is another one for NI, but I forgot what it was called). Reboot.
- Install the "Keysight IO Libraries Suite", version "2020 Update 1". Reboot.

Now I was able to see the device in the "Keysight Connection Expert", which is Keysight's analogue to "NI-MAX".
After installing Anaconda Python (64-bit) and running `pip install pyvisa`, I could control the instruments without any errors.